# Are there any good reasons to avoid using the noscript tag in an HTML5 header?

Tags: html, headers, noscript

I need an efficient and aesthetically-pleasing way to gracefully degrade site appearance for users with Javascript disabled and, while I am not aware of any problem with adding a link to an alternative stylesheet wrapped in `noscript` tags in the document header [w/HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-noscript-element), I figured it couldn't hurt to ask before going that route.

**Update:** Example document to demonstrate undesirable behavior when using JS to hide elements

This document reliably shows a red blink while the browser repaints the window contents when I test with a hard refresh in Internet Explorer 8.0 (note that I had to add a fairly large image to get IE to exhibit this behavior - I expect that this will appear in IE whenever resources are low).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>See the blink?</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#blinky').css('display','none');
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color:#000000;
}
div#blinky {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/9712/orionfull_jcc_big.jpg" height="1" width="1" />
<div id="blinky">
<h1>Did you see it?</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I refuse to upgrade until I absolutely have to, so I believe my somewhat-underpowered desktop is representative of the lowest common denominator of the user experience; I can't guarantee that you'll be able to duplicate on a high-end machine with ample resources available but you're welcome to give it a try to see what I mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general it's better to use *progressive enhancement* rather than *graceful degradation*. This means essentially starting with the content as if the user has no scripting, then using Javascript to enhance the page.

For example, you might start with a link/button that goes somewhere or submits a form. Then you add Javascript that prevents naivgation/submission and does something else instead.

For your specific case, I can't think of a good reason to add a stylesheet in noscript tags. Why not add the styles to your main stylesheet? If there is a clash of styles, I would start with the noscript ones applied then use Javascript to add a single class/ID on a parent element which changes the styles.

Comment: RE: progressive enhancement - you're preaching to the choir, however, as this is a case where I can't wait for Javascript to hide the content as the page loads, (that behavior is not aesthetically pleasing to the artist I'm designing the site for) I am looking for caveats specific to using noscript in this manner.

Comment: If you run your javascript after the DOM has loaded but before the page is displayed they shouldn't be seeing anything actually happen on screen.

Comment: **@John Conde** - Added an example document which exhibits the behavior in question when viewed in IE 8.0 on my machine.

Comment: My question was a lame duck (in the future I'll know *not* to ask "why not" questions) and your answer represents best practices, though HTML5 does allow `<noscript>` in the header and IE continues its regrettable glitchiness.